# After upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 Suspend, Restart and Power Off does not work

Tags: nvidia, suspend, laptop, 17.10

I have this very annoying problem, I have a laptop and when close the lid and reopen again, the computer does not start any more, showing a list of services loaded with "[OK]" but nothing more. I need to press the power button some seconds to power off completely closing all applications.

On the other hand, when I try to restart or Power Off after click on the icon in the topbar, then the message "The system will power off.." and buttons to select the action to do, take over 30 seconds to appear the first time. Anyway selecting Restart or Power off close the session, showing a loading screen but the computer does not Power off or restart never.

Tried:

- [X] Different versions of Nvidia Driver.
- [X] Disable Nividia drivers and using only Intel
- [X] Wayland, Xorg

Details:

[image]

Any suggestion will be very welcome, I really need help with this annoying problem, I can't move with the laptop without closing all applications :X

Answer (score 4):

After many tests the following solution works for me:

Login using Xorg does not use Wayland has many errors yet, anyway the login screen still uses Wayland, to disable the Wayland in the login screen:

`sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

Uncomment the line `WaylandEnable=false` to force the login screen to use Xorg

```
[daemon]
# Uncoment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false
```

Restart!

Comment: thanks @rafrsr! - i had the same issue after upgrading to 17.10 on my System76 Oryx Pro - this resolved it

Comment: Uncommenting "WaylandEnable=false" (and rebooting) did the trick for me!  My X1 Carbon Gen4 with Ubuntu 17.10 suspends perfectly now.  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Open "Software & Updates" open"Additional Drivers" tab and select X.Org
        Xserver

[image: Software and Updates]

Now Logout and click on the gear icon and Select "Ubuntu on Xorg"

[image: login screen]

That's it. :D You won't face this issue again.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the question because a) it implies using another driver,  b) it tells the user to use Xorg when he has stated he tried it already.

Answer (score -2):

Ran into the same thing with Ubuntu 17.10 on an Asus X550J laptop. Originally had upgraded from 17.04, tried to a clean install of 17.10. Tried all of the various driver suggestions; updating grub; etc. Finally found the solution -- BIOS settings.

On Asus computers you boot into BIOS settings by holding down the Escape key while the computer powers up. Once in BIOS tab to the Advanced settings and you'll see **Wake on Lid Open** and **Power Off Energy Saving**. I disabled both of those, rebooted, and now I can finally shut the lid on the laptop without it just powering off the system or getting frozen.

Hope that helps someone else avoid some hair pulling.

Comment: I see someone marked this answer down, curious why.

Comment: I would say they voted down because your suggestion is dangerous since the laptop may overheat and meltdown if its told to stay awake when lid is shut ... by accident my ubuntu laptop failed to powerdown when I closed the lid then after sitting in my backpack for hours so its exhaust fan vent holes where blocked I could smell it super over heating