# Ubuntu 17.10 not shutting down

Tags: shutdown, 17.10

my laptop is not shutting down and instead it keeps showing the following

https://youtu.be/yj92AAMnPV8

and it only shut downs when i press the power button

Comment: It seems you are using Nvidia card. Which one do you have? Did you try to install proprietary drivers from *Software & updates* (*Additional Drivers* tab)?

Comment: @N0rbert i have Nvidia Geforce 920MX but i deactivated the proprietary drivers after gnome became so sluggish and i used xorg instead.also i noticed that the proprietary drivers makes the fan spins very fast and the sensors temperatures are exceeding 50 Degree Celsius and without the proprietary drivers they dont exceed 37

Comment: I have a similar issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/968070/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10-suspend-restart-and-power-off-does-not-work) but restart and suspend does not work either. If you find a solution, please publish here. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Nvidia driver helped me. From command prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

Comment: When i installed nvidia drivers i stucked on a black screen during booting

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nvidia site](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/123918/en-us) you should use their proprietary drivers version 384.90.

They [are available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia+384&searchon=names&suite=artful&section=all) in Ubuntu artful repositories.

You should install them and use *Ubuntu on Xorg* session.

Comment: I have a similar issue (https://askubuntu.com/questions/968070/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10-suspend-restart-and-power-off-does-not-work) and tried with all nvidia drivers and the problem persist :(