# Ubuntu 17.10 lock issues

Tags: suspend, 17.10, lock-screen

Is anyone experiencing issues when waking your computer up from a lock screen? On multiple occasions the system has been unresponsive on a mouse click or pressing keys, and i've had to turn my computer off using the power button.. I've had about 4 - 6 occurrences of this and I don't want to damage my HD with these resets. I never had this issue with 16.04, seems very peculiar.

Check this out [LockScreen Issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968070/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10-suspend-restart-and-power-off-does-not-work/972147#972147)

Comment: "Is anyone experiencing issues when waking your computer up from a lock screen?" – **Apparently not**. What is your *actual* question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Found the issue ~ a bug with the wifi.. here's the link to the issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724317

Comment: That bug report seems only vaguely similar to your description. It doesn't help that the latter is already quite vague itself.